# why isn't $computer_choice random?

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin

so i've never really took any classes in programming, i've only followed a few tutorials on youtube and tried to start coding myself from scratch. i'm trying to make this coin flip program in nano but it doesn't seem to work. when i choose H (heads) i sometimes win or lose but when i chose T (Tails) it says "you lose" twice.

the terminal i'm using is cygwin which for some reason doesn't allow C++. i don't even know if the randomize function works.

```
printf "(H) heads or (T) tails"
read user_choice
if [ $user_choice != H ] && [ $user_choice != T ]; then
  echo invalid choice defaulting to heads
  user_choice=H=1
  user_choice=T=0
fi
#value of 1 is heads, 2 is Tails
computer_choice=$(($RANDOM% 2 + 1))
if [ $computer_choice == 1 ]; then
  echo computer chooses tails
fi
if [ $computer_choice == 1 ] && [ $user_choice = H ]; then
  echo you win!
else
  echo you lose
  if [ $computer_choice == 2 ] && [ $user_choice = T ]; then
    echo you win!
    echo computer chooses heads
  else
    echo you lose
  fi
fi
```

i expect to see "you win" or "you lose" however, you only maybe see you win when you choose heads and you'll always lose when chosing tails but you see it twice. once again i have very little experience with any programming language. if anyone could explain what's going wrong that would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Sometimes you forgot the `$` in front of variables, for instance `computer_choice`. Have a look at https://www.shellcheck.net/. Also this assignments of the form `user_choice=H=1` look odd. Did you mean `user_choice=H`?

Comment: @Socowi so i've adjusted it but you still only win when chosing H and you still lose twice when selecting T

Comment: Edit your question so that we can see your current version. Please keep the formatting in mind.

Comment: @Socowi eddited. sorry, still new

Comment: `user_choice=H=1` is still there. By the way, `$computer_choice` is random. The error is in the last part where you check for the result. I could give you a correct script, but then you wouldn't learn much. Look at your program and think about this: Why are there *two* `echo you win!`and *two* `echo you lose`? And why is the code not symmetric?

Comment: As an aside, Cygwin does have C++. But you are doing this with a shell script, so I'm not sure why that's relevant.

Anyway, @Socowi has given you all the information that you need to fix your script. Why do you echo "computer chooses tails" and then not "computer chooses heads until after echoing "you lose"? Why echo "you lose" followed by "you win!"?

Comment: @Socowi sup dude, i've fixed it and it's now functioning the way it should! thank you for the tips and insight!

Comment: @liteversion Glad to hear. You can answer your own question. By accepting your own answer you can close this question and gain reputation. Your answer will also help others with similar problems in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf "(H) heads or (T) tails"
read user_choice
if [ $user_choice != H ] && [ $user_choice != T ]; then
  echo invalid choice defaulting to heads
 $user_choice=H=1
 $user_choice=T=2
fi
#value of 1 is heads, 2 is Tails
computer_choice=$(($RANDOM% 2 + 1))
if [ $computer_choice == 1 ]; then
  echo computer chooses heads
elif [ $computer_choice == 2 ]; then
echo computer chooses tails
fi
if [ $computer_choice == 1 ] && [ $user_choice = H ]; then
  echo you win!
else
if [ $computer_choice == 2 ] && [ $user_choice = T ]; then
    echo you win!
  else
    echo you lose
  fi
fi
```